# Pivoting the data in a key value pair table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I have a standard table like this:

```
MyKey   MyValue
--------------------------------
Var1    20
Var2    30
Var3    20
Var4    15
Var5    6
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
Var1        Var2        Var3        Var4
--------------------------------------------
20          30          20          15
```

The data is not grouped, or calculated.  I've found and tried a number of things so far:

```
SELECT 
    Var1,
    Var2,
    Var2,
    Var4
FROM 
    (select * 
     from MyTable
    ) T
PIVOT
(
    max(MyValue)
    FOR MyKey in 
    (
        'Var1', 'Var2', 'Var3', 'Var4'
    )
)
as V
```

This works, but I get multiple rows.

Also, I tried using CASE ... WHEN:

```
Select MyValue,
 Min(Case MyKey When 'Var1' Then MyKey End) Var1,
 Min(Case MyKey When 'Var2' Then MyKey End) Var2,
 ...
 FROM MyTable
 WHERE MyKey in 
 ('Var1', 'Var2', ...)
```

This doesn't work because I have nothing to group on.

Is what I'm trying to do possible, and if so, how?

EDIT:

Okay, I think I've determined what's causing the difference, I've edited the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29d63/1).  Basically, the table has an IDENTITY column.  I didn't realise this would make a different, but it makes a marked on.

Comment: can you please add more data to standard table and expected data?

Comment: How does the result of your pivot differ from what you are expecting? I have [replicated your pivot on sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/15365/2) (albeit with a minor correction) and the result appears to be exactly what you are expecting.

Comment: You have mentioned that `I get multiple rows` but when i tried running above query with mentioned input table , I didn't get multiple values.SQL Fiddle demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c16b8/4

Comment: The pivot I'm running includes every row in the table.  I've edited my question slightly.  In the example above - the pivot returns 5 rows rather than 1.

Comment: I've updated the post, as I would appear I didn't originally provide sufficient information to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [`SQL Fiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72cd4/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([pk] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
     [MyKey] nvarchar(4) not null, 
     [MyValue] nvarchar(30) not null)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([MyKey], [MyValue])
VALUES
    ('Var1', '20'), ('Var2', '30'),
    ('Var3', '20'), ('Var4', '15'),
    ('Var5', 'aaa')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
    Var1,
    Var2,
    Var3,
    Var4
FROM 
    (select [MyKey], [MyValue]
     from Table1
    ) AS T
PIVOT
(
    max(MyValue)
    FOR MyKey in 
    (
        Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4
    )
)
 AS V
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72cd4/1/0)**:

```
| VAR1 | VAR2 | VAR3 | VAR4 |
|------|------|------|------|
|   20 |   30 |   20 |   15 |
```

Comment: This does work (as apparently did my original example of a pivot).  I've updated the post to highlight why I was seeing a problem.

Comment: It doesn't seem to.  The SQL Fiddle example doesn't include the ID column

Comment: @pm_2 You are doing "SELECT * from Table" which includes Identity column see this [`SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29d63/2)